# Date Range of the x-th week in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know the year and the index of the week, i.e. 2014, the 5th week. how can I find out the starting and ending date of this week in SQL Server? I do not really care whether the week starting with Monday or Sunday.

In mySQL, it has a MakeDate which may be able to do this. Is there an existing way to do this in SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @date DATE='2014-01-01'

SELECT Dateadd(dd, -( Datepart(dw, Dateadd(wk, 5, @date) - 1) ), Dateadd(wk, 5, @date)) [WeekStart],
       Dateadd(dd, 7 - ( Datepart(dw, Dateadd(wk, 5, @date)) ), Dateadd(wk, 5, @date))  [WeekEnd]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  dateadd(wk,5,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) as firstdayof5thweek2014,
  dateadd(dd,6,dateadd(wk,5,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0))) as lastdayof5thweek2014
```

SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0) ==>gives you start day of the current year

SELECT dateadd(wk,5,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) ==> On top add 5 weeks to get the start date of 5th week in 2014

SELECT dateadd(dd,6,dateadd(wk,5,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0))) ==> On top add 6 days to get the last date of 5th week in 2014